# How to reduce the amout of values from cv2.inRange

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am building a bot for a game and I detect walls using a mask, extracting all the values and making a very tiny screenshot around the player.

If there is a wall it will detect it. However even the smallest wall is so many values. I use [0] and [-1] to get both of the corners but it still slows it down a lot just because it unpacks
thousounds of values. All of them go like this

(46, 98), (47, 98), (48, 98), (49, 98), (50, 98), (51, 98), (52, 98), (53, 98)```

Just completely
pointless to have them all. Is there a way to group them so it doesn't unpack every single one. I tried

```
            image = cv.cvtColor(around_player_img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
            lower_rgb, upper_rgb = self.walls['chocolate_wall']
            lower = np.array([(7, 165, 235)])
            upper = np.array((8, 168, 255))

            # old 7 163 0 8 168 255
            mask = cv.inRange(image, lower, upper)
            walls = np.nonzero(mask)
            walls_coords = list(zip(*walls[::-1]))
            print(f"FOudn walls --> {walls_coords}")
```

walls[:5:-1] to skip every 5 but it just breaks it.

Comment: You've got all your coordinates in `walls_coords` as a list of tuples. Create another list containing every 5th coordinate like this: `reduced_walls_coords = walls_coords[::5]`. You can verify by checking the length of both the lists.

Comment: what's even the purpose of listing them all? **don't do that!** just keep the `mask` around!

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz because i need the coords. If theres a wall in radius of 40 pixels from the player it should try to navigate around it. For exampe if the player is at (x=512, y=412) and there is a way exactly below him (x=512, y=440) i need it to go the right for like 50 pixels and try again. I haven't figured exactly how i am going to make it navigate around i need to have the walls first.

Comment: collision avoidance? then you don't need a list of pixels. you just need to know how far away the nearest wall is, and maybe what direction, right? what logic (code) do you have for that so far? I need to assess how difficult my proposed solution can be... because my solution would involve using `affineWarp` to send out feelers into the scene (the mask), like ultrasound distance sensors. the concept is simple, simple usage, but if matrices offend you, this may be unsuitable.

Comment: perhaps post the mask image (add to your question). -- if this is a maze, you'd do better to solve the maze in its entirety, rather than implementing a simple "follow the wall" rule. that requires extracting the maze, possibly simplifying the graph, and then applying a shortest path algorithm.

Comment: Hello thanks for the help. I don't have any logic code for it so far. Just get the first and last value from the list of values from the mask and thats the 2 corners of the wall. And then screenshot the wall to see the result. But it's just too slow because of the 9214124 values so heres the game image and the mask -> https://imgur.com/a/UpBgWiH also important the way my character moves is by dragging the mouse to the joystick in the bottom left and calculate the degrees of the line between the players center and the destination center with math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / math.pi

Comment: And then set the cursor to the joystick and move it by left or right and up or down by 2% of the degrees. It goes to every point like that but walls stop it